# How do I make a number in a StringVariable increase by 1 every 5 seconds in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, time, intermediate-code

So i've been coding a Cookie Clicker prototype in Tkinter and I stumbled with this problem:

I first made an option that when pressed, makes every click worth 2 points(It has a price).

Then I wanted to make another option that when pressed, it would add up 1 point every 5 seconds
but I haven't found a way to make it work (I have not set the price because it doesn't work yet).

```
from tkinter import *
import time
#funciones y variables

clicks = 0
incrementer = 1
price1 = 1
loop1 = 0


def sumar():
    global clicks
    clicks += incrementer
    you.set("Has dado " +str(clicks)+ " clicks")

def shop1():
    global clicks
    global incrementer
    if clicks < price1:
        return
    elif clicks >= price1:
        clicks -= price1
        incrementer = 2
        you.set("Has dado " +str(clicks)+ " clicks")
        buy1.destroy()
        buy2.place(x=52, y=155)

def shop2():
    global loop1
    loop1 = int(1)
    buy2.destroy()

while loop1 == 1:
    interface.update()
    time.sleep(5)
    clicks += 1
    you.set("Has dado " + str(clicks) + " clicks")


#Ventana y su configuración

interface = Tk()
interface.title("Cokie Test")
interface.geometry("200x200")
interface.resizable(False, False)
interface.configure(bg="black")

#Botón y changeable value
buy2 = Button(interface, bg="black", fg="white", text="Comprar Auto 1", command=shop2)

buy1 = Button(interface, bg="black", fg="white", text="Comprar x2", command=shop1)
buy1.place(x=62, y=155)
clickerimg = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Eduardo/OneDrive/Escritorio/Programming/botoncito.png")
clicker = Button(interface, command=sumar)
clicker.config(image=clickerimg)
clicker.pack(pady=20)

you = StringVar()
you.set("Has dado 0 clicks")
clickss = Label(interface, bg="black",fg="white", textvariable=you)
clickss.place(x=49,y=123)



interface.mainloop()
```

So I tried this expecting that it would add up 1 point every 5 seconds

```
def shop2():
    global loop1
    loop1 = int(1)
    buy2.destroy()

while loop1 == 1:
    interface.update()
    time.sleep(5)
    clicks += 1
    you.set("Has dado " + str(clicks) + " clicks")
```

but it didn't respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter widgets have a method named `after` that can be used to schedule functions to run in the future. If that function itself calls `after` to reschedule itself, it will continue to run for the life of the application.

The first argument to `after` is a delay in milliseconds. The second argument is a reference to a function. Any additional arguments are passed to that function as positional arguments.

Here's a very simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def tick():
    value = points.get()
    points.set(value+1)
    root.after(5000, tick)


root = tk.Tk()

points = tk.IntVar(root, value=0)
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=points)
label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

tick()

root.mainloop()
```